# CSS-precompiler LESS and/or SASS

Tags: css

Is there a way to **avoid working with the command-line** installing and using LESS??
There are several offers for GUIs for the compiling-phase, but I did not find a way for the Installation-Phase.

I have been working in the IT-business for so many decades (more in the mainframe and midrange area and as a project-manager and programmer in the application development) and could by now avoid to go as far down to the command-line-world.

I did develop quite fine Websites using HTML5 and CSS3 and doint this I felt a desire for all that, what LESS and/or SASS are offering and the Syntax and logics dont look difficult to handle. But I fail in the first step of just installing it.

The LESS-Website offers command-lines to key in. But I am not sure, if this will be all I have to key in, but only the significant line to be embedded in a sequence of other commands very familiar to all those working at this Level.
How do I e.g. define the place to store the Installation and to refer to in the href in the link-Statement of my html-file ....  ??

Thanks 
Gerhard (from Vienna/Austria, living in Trier, Germany)

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Less is a CSS pre-processor. if you are include less.js in you html page

You can use less directly in to your html page.
Other ways you can use less compiler 
[Kola](http://koala-app.com/) this is an open source application it will help you to compile less to css

Comment: My Problem: I am not familiar to work with the command-line. Is there another way? Is ">> hpm install -g less" all I have to do, or has this to be embedded in additional cryptical commands, linking to my Folders e.g.??? Of course, I could just try. But I rather ask.

Answer (score 0):

Your Topics are clear to me. I even downloaded Koala already and I have no Problem in including less.js in my html. And I have read Bass Jobsens book about the Syntax, which does not seem to raise great Problems to me.

But before working with it, I will have to download LESS -what I have done from the Less-Website to the Folder of my choice. My Problem is the next necessary step: To install this downloaded program. There is no install.exe or something like that. The book as well as the info in the less-Website tell me to key some crpytic commands into the command-line.